# Функция array_filter()

Tags: php

В общем, такая ситуация. На локалке у меня `PHP 5.4` и данная функция работает корректно. На хостинге версия 5.2. Из-за этого скрипт перестает работать. Подскажите, как это можно поправить?

```
 $tree_real = array_filter($tree_real,function($item)
                    { 
                        return $item['name']== __(Request::initial()->controller());
                    }
               );
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Помог вот такой в моей ситуации быдлокод

```
public function action_index()
{
$categories = ORM::factory('categorie')
            ->order_by('name_cat')
    ->find_all();
    $count = ORM::factory('categorie')
            ->count_all();

    /*Создаем многомерный массив с данными из БД для древовидного меню
     * $tree_menu = array(
     *      0 => array(
     *          'id' => 1,
     *          'p_id' => 0,
     *          'name_cat' => name
     *          ),
     *      1 => array(
     *          'id' => 2,
     *          'p_id' => 0,
     *          'name_cat' => name
     *          ),
     *      ...
     * )
     */

    $tree = array();
    foreach($categories as $category)
    {
        $category_array = array(
            'id' => $category->code,
            'parent_id' => $category->p_id,
            'name' => $category->name_cat,
        );
        array_push($tree, $category_array);
    }

    $tree_real_2 = $this->array2tree($tree, 0);
    //print_r($tree_real);

    /*$tree_real = array_filter($tree_real,function($item)
                { 
                    return $item['name']== __(Request::initial()->controller());
                }
                );*/
    switch(Request::initial()->controller())
    {
        case 'stationery': $i = 6;
            break;
        case 'materials': $i = 8;
            break;
        case 'souvenirs': $i = 5;
            break;
        case 'school': $i = 31;
            break;
        default: $i = 6;
    }
    $tree_real_2 = $tree_real_2[$i];
    $tree_real[$i] = $tree_real_2;

    $this->template->tree_real = $tree_real;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Как то так:

```
      $tree_real = array_filter($tree_real,'some_f');
      function some_f($item){
        return $item['name']== __(Request::initial()->controller());
      }
```

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Comment: The second argument, 'some_f', should be a valid callback

Comment: проверьте внимательно синтаксис. на php 5.2 отлично работает даже без нотайсов.

Comment: я копировал Ваш код

Comment: Какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: есть возможность код посмотреть? вполне возможен вариант, что Вы скопировали мой кусок кода в какой либо уже существующий метод, либо неверно расставлены фигурные скобки. вынесите объявление функции за пределы класса.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
$tree_real = array_filter($tree_real, create_function('$item', 'return $item["name"]== __(Request::initial()->controller());');
```

Answer (score -1):

Может все таки так:

```
$tree_real = array_filter($tree_real,function($item)
                    { 
                        return $item['name']= __(Request::initial()->controller());
                    }
               );
```

Comment: В чем разница с тем, что я нипасал в вопросе?

Comment: что бы присвоить переменной значение нужно одно `=` а не два `==`

Comment: В данном случае я сравниваю и в случае равенства возвращаю

Comment: А разве замыкание в ПШП появилось не с версии 5.3 ?  
ТС хочет применить замыкание на 5.2 отсюда и ловит ошибку.

Comment: Вот в этом проблема. Как на версии 5.2 обойти это. На 5.4 все работает отлично

Comment: @demyan112rv, просто сделайте именованную функцию. Как уже было сказано. Код @FLK у Вас не работает скорее всего по причине несоответствия контекста исполнения (области видимости переменных).